# Correct statistical analysis for comparison of two groups with 5 subgroups (in R)

Tags: r, ordinal-data, biostatistics

I need to find the correct way to compare the following:

I have 500 patients split into two groups (Seazure and No-Seazure)

The groups characteristics match (age, gender etc. is non significant)

The comparison variable is WFNS-grading:

grade 1: GCS 15, no motor deficit. grade 2: GCS 13-14 without deficit grade 3: GCS 13-14 with focal neurological deficit grade 4: GCS 7-12, with or without deficit. grade 5: GCS <7 , with or without deficit.

I just can't able to find the median or the Mean because the grades Are more like A-E.

So what statistical analysis do I need to use to calculate if the severity (grading) is significant different between Seazure and No-Seazure.

I am using R, to make My calculations

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? I.e. do you have a clear question you wish to address? Whether differences in the characteristics of groups are significant or not is not usually considered an useful, reliable or acceptable criterion for determining what should play a role in the analysis.

Comment: My question is: i there a significant difference in the two groups severity of SAH (WFNS)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seizure grade appears to be an ordinal variable. There are a few options for these. One is to use a test such as Jonckheere-Terpstra. In R, one way to do this is `jonckheere.test`.  Another method is to treat this as a regression problem with ordinal logistic regression. Then "grade" would be the dependent variable and "group" would be the independent variable. One nice thing about ordinal regression (vs. JT) is that you can include covariates. However, ordinal logistic regression makes more assumptions that JT.

Comment: Logistic Regression. Of course.. I think i overthought it... Thx

Comment: Would you use something like polr(DCI~Age+Gender+WFNS...?

Comment: That looks about right.